# Is there a way to exit a while loop without Ctrl+C (bash)

Tags: command-line, bash

I'm trying to run a simple loop that while the condition is true it sends some logs to the system.

example:

```
while sleep 1800; do
 top -b > /path/to-file.txt
 ping xx.xx.xx.xx > /path/to-file2.txt
 ps -ef > /path/to-file3.txt
done
```

but it looks like even after sleep 1800 the loop is not exiting and continues to run.

is there any way to create an exit point after half an hour passed? (aka 1800 seconds )

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out.

Using a while loop from the beginning wasn't the best idea.
i used for loop like this and it solved my problem:

```
TOP_LOG=/path/to/top-output.txt
PS_LOG=/path/to/ps-out-put.txt


for ((i = 0; i < $COUNT_TIME; ++i)); do
    top -b -n 1 > $TOP_LOG
    ps -ef > $PS_LOG
    echo "${i}"
    sleep 10
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Your snippet in the question doesn't work because `while` actually runs the command and captures the exit code. If the exit code is 0 (true) the loop continues and breaks otherwise.

You can use the `$SECONDS` variable to get the current time in seconds.

Solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
END=$((SECONDS+1800))
while [ $SECONDS -lt $END ]; do
    top -b > /path/to-file.txt
    ping xx.xx.xx.xx > /path/to-file2.txt
    ps -ef > /path/to-file3.txt
done
```